# what can i use instead of float or int if i want to show the zeros after point like number = 1.200

Tags: python-3.x

**i am adding two number with point **

number = float(str(num1)+"."+str(num2))

> i am using them as index so when num1 = 1 and num2 = 200 it returns number = 1.2 instead I need
> number = 1.200 how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

Here is simpler approach:

```
number = 1.2
print(number)
print(type(number))

number_of_zeros = 3
number_B = str(number) + "0" * number_of_zeros
print(number_B)
print(type(number_B))

number_C = format(number, f".{number_of_zeros+1}f")
print(number_C)
print(type(number_C))
```

Output:

```
1.2
<class 'float'>
1.2000
<class 'str'>
1.2000
<class 'str'>
```